Collision with a frictionless movable inclined plane
After deriving an expression for the distance travelled along a fixed incline plane by a particle on colliding with it when dropped vertically, out of my own interest, I was wondering whether an expression can be derived when the wedge is not fixed.
Variables:

$m$ - mass of the particle
$M$ - mass of the inclined plane
$e$ - coefficient of restitution
$\theta$ - angle of inclination of the inclined plane
$u$ - initial vertical velocity of the particle before collision

Unknowns:

$v$ - horizontal velocity of the inclined plane after collision
$v_x$ - horizontal component of velocity of the particle after collision
$v_y$ - vertical component of velocity of the particle after collision
$t$ - time taken between the two collisions of the particle and the inclined plane
$R$ - distance travelled by the particle along the inclined plane

I was able to come up with only four equations by working in the frame of the inclined plane, so as to use the concept of relative velocity:
$$e=\frac{v_y\cos\theta+v_x\sin\theta+v\sin\theta}{u\cos\theta} \\ mv_x=Mv \\ t=\frac{2(v_y\cos\theta+v_x\sin\theta+v\sin\theta)}{g\cos\theta} \\ R=(v_x\cos\theta-v_y\sin\theta+v\cos\theta)t+\frac{1}{2}gt^2\sin\theta.$$
They are based off of the definition of the coefficient of restitution, conservation of linear momentum in the horizontal direction, the time period of a projectile, and the second equation of kinematics applied along the inclined plane respectively.
However, I am unable to think of another equation that would make this system of equations solvable. Please let me know what your thoughts are.

How about conservation of total mechanical energy?

@BobD I thought of trying to use that, but the total mechanical energy of the system will be conserved only if it's a perfectly elastic collision.

You didn’t say the collision was inelastic.  If it is you’d better edit your post to say that

I see now that you did specify a coefficient of restitution
